# Java or Spring: two-way encryption with salt?

Tags: java, spring, encryption

I am doing a web project with Spring.

I am hoping to do a two-way encryption (and decryption) of a few url parameters. I don't need very strong encryption.

I googled but found many are related to one-way password encryption, which is not what wanted.

Can any expert out there point me to the right place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can recommend really nice library called bouncy castle. On their homepage is a few nice examples. See https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html

Another possibility is java crypto api and something like

```
SecretKey keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
Cipher aesCbc = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
aesCbc.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
byte[] encryptedBytes = aesCbc.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
return Base64.encodeBase64String(encryptedBytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can you use classes from [javax.crypto](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/package-summary.html) to perform encryption and decryption.